# ext3 partition randomly mounts read-only

Tags: linux, centos, ext3

The /var partition randomly mounts read-only, when I reboot it mounts as rw again.

```
OS: CentOS 5.4 
partition: /var, size: 80G
the /var is for web logs and MySQL data file.
```

Comment: Will the OP ever come back to choose an answer, will a bounty be worth it?

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a hardware problem with your disk, or corruption from some other reason. When a file system errors is detected, the filesystem is usually remounted read only.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities are:

1. Ext3 filesystem errors
2. Disk IO bottleneck OR HDD issues.

First thing you must check whether the HDD IO and it's functionality, performance. In order check the IO please take a look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181962/how-to-interpret-iostat).

```
iostat -x -d
```

(will do the trick)

If you have filesystem error, boot your server into single user mode then run,

```
fsck -a -f
```

this will resolve your filesystem issue.